# 90 degree soft close lid support for 80lb lid?

Tags: cabinetry

I bought a very large chest made of teak and mounted a 50" LED TV to the inside of the lid so we could hide the it when it wasn't in use.  The lid (with the tv mounted) is about 80 lbs and 24" from hinge to lip.  I want something that keeps the lid open at 90 degrees and keeps the lid from slamming when it closes.  The best thing I've found are a pair of these [Stabilus gas springs](http://truck-hardware.orrorr.com/item/refrigerators/ll-categories-gas-springs-gas-springs-for-cabinets/8031uw?) but they can only handle 56lbs.  Is there a better product for this application?

[image: Chest Closed]
[image: Chest Open]
[image: Side of chest where support will be mounted]

Comment: Could you put on a picture, would help me have a clearer image. Thanks

Comment: @Ljk2000 Good idea, I added some photos.

Comment: This made me think of torsion hinges, and the claim "Support any size lid by simply adding more hinges." But the calculator claimed your 960 inch-pounds is over the recommended limit. (And would cost a ton in the hinge increments sold by the vendor.)

Comment: Nice chest and clever idea!

Comment: Rear-hatch gas struts for an SUV or minivan might do the trick, though they wouldn't look spectacular.

Comment: There are certainly gas struts that can handle a heavy load -- but the example I'm thinking of also has a very solid framework to support them; have you considered how you could mount them so they won't rip free? Note that as the lid lifts, weight will progressively be shifted to the hinges, so the major force is at the almost-closed end of the swing. (For reference only: http://www.rockler.com/bed-lift-mechanisms-side-mount-option-horizontal)

Answer (score 5):

A commercial grade door closer might do the trick.  A door closer can be set with a limit to prevent the door from opening too far, and can close the door once triggered.  It gets its power when the user initially opens the door.  In your case, you would rig the closer in reverse to assist (close) when you open the lid and resist when closing it.  The important thing is that commercial doors are heavy and the closers should be strong enough to offer real assistance in your setup. A good commercial carpenter would be able to assist you on selecting the right style of closer and how to rig it in the cabinet.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this will work.  It would help with closing so that the lid doesn't slam but it wouldn't keep the door open, would it?

Comment: You can't necessarily reverse the action on these things either.

Comment: @ Tom Krones Closers also come with hold open features.  They will stay in a fixed open position until sufficient force is applied to close them.

Comment: @Chris H  There are a wide variety of closers available and commercial hardware suppliers often have experienced hardware specifiers who will be able to identify a closer that will work.  Many closers work on a hydraulic cylinder and even though they pull a door closed, they will not slam it, they work at a slow pace.  One problem in this situation is that the action must accommodate heavy loads and the user may need assistance lifting and lowering. I,m not positive if this will meet the situation adequately, but it has a strong chance of doing so.

Comment: @Ashlar I'm familiar with the hydraulic sort and can't see how they would adapt as their main feature is a damping action. If there are other types designed to assist opening that could be of interest.

Comment: @Ashlar, I like the idea but I don't want to hire a carpenter, I want to do this project myself.  Do you have any recommendations on the exact door opener to use?

Comment: @ Tom Krones No, there are too many specialty types and manufacturers. Try going to a commercial hardware supply house that supplies contractors (not a big box store).  They have very experienced hardware specialists at their service desk who should be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you've read the detailed specs on the gas springs, because simply taking the pressure from the website and equating that to the mass won't work. They may still do for damping the closing movement.

Automotive gas springs may have a higher load.

If you want it to hold at 90 degrees you'll need some kind of stop. And the lid will be nearly balanced at this point. So some big rare-earth magnets in the stop may be what you need. You can buy them with a countersunk hole for screw fixing, though I suggest also sinking them into pockets with just enough recessing that they don't hit each other.

I've taken the whole weight of a decent size monitor on quite small magnets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris.  I've read the specs of the gas springs but that doesn't mean I understand everything.  :)  I found some 200N gas springs (http://www.amazon.com/Apexstone-Spring-Strut-Shock-Support/dp/B01CMI5ZE8/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1465074528&sr=8-6) that are rated to 90lbs together but it sounds like it might not be that easy?

Comment: You need to calculate or measure the force needed to hold it open, and check that the gas springs can deliver that force at that extension (which you can figure out with trigonometry). I used them in an engineering context years ago and I remember that they gave the force at full extension. You can measure the force by lifting with a spring balance (even luggage scales) if you have one big enough.